# Why is it difficult to define n-category?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, definition, higher-category-theory

Forgive me for the vagueness in the following paragraph, but I don't know how to communicate what I am thinking more formally.

If we have a definition for 1-categories (category) and a definition for 2-categories then surely we can abstract this to 3-categories, 4… all the way to infinity. From what I understand the main obstacle in defining the n-category is that two definitions of a category are equivalent if the category of said categories is equivalent, and so we are stuck in a loop. (I may not be communicating what I mean properly here..) But is it not the case that the infinite-category contains the n-category for all n, allowing us to stop the loop of cyclically defining categories? So my question is, what are the main obstacles in creating a definition for the n-category? Please note that I have had limit exposure to category theory (adjunction's, Yoneda…) and much less exposure to higher category theory, so a not overly technical explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's easy to define *strict* $n$-categories (meaning that composition is strictly associative at all levels and so forth): if you have a definition of strict $n-1$-category, you just define strict $n$-categories to be categories enriched over strict $n-1$-categories. The problem is first that many natural examples aren't strict, although when $n = 2$ you can hope to strictify them, and more importantly that when $n \ge 3$ many natural examples aren't strictifiable at all.

For example, whatever an $n$-category ought to be, every topological space ought to have a fundamental $n$-groupoid whose objects are points, whose morphisms are paths, whose $2$-morphisms are homotopies, and so forth. This is not naturally a strict $n$-groupoid (composition of paths is already not associative, but only associative "up to coherent higher homotopy"), and when $n \ge 3$ it generally isn't strictifiable: it turns out that strictifiability implies that [Whitehead brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_product) vanish, and so already the fundamental $3$-groupoid of $S^2$ is not equivalent to a strict $3$-groupoid.

The difficulty of defining $n$-categories comes from figuring out all the coherence data and conditions necessary to define *weak* $n$-categories so that they capture, at the very least, $n$-groupoids as they arise in algebraic topology (see also the [homotopy hypothesis](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+hypothesis)). To get a sense of how hard this is to do "by hand," see, for example, [Todd Trimble's definition of a weak $4$-category](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/trimble/tetracategories.html).

Even with strict $n$-groupoids, the naive way of defining what a functor is between these also fails to capture topological phenomena: for example, every group $G$ gives rise to a strict groupoid $BG$ with one object and automorphisms $G$, and every abelian group $A$ gives rise to a strict $2$-groupoid $B^2 A$ with one object, one morphism, and $2$-automorphisms $A$. The "correct" set of equivalence classes of morphisms $BG \to B^2 A$ is the second cohomology group $H^2(BG, A)$, but the naive description of a functor between strict $2$-groupoids won't get you this. The problem is that functors also cannot be taken to strictly preserve composition, etc. but must also come with coherence data and conditions.

Comment: Just my two cents, but I tend to think a lot of that "notorious complexity" comes from trying to reduce natural families of structure/axioms to generators for that family structure/axioms. The same thing happens in elementary algebra when, instead of just saying "okay, in a monoid you can compose finite sequences of elements, possibly empty; and composition satisfies this natural looking family of laws", algebraists of a more classical bent say something like "you can compose pairs, and you've got this special $1$ element, and a few ill-motivated identities hold."

Comment: @goblin: things are still hard. As far as I know all of the standard proposals that work for all $n$ avoid the problem you describe (see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-category). That's one place you might run into trouble, but there's a more important place, which is that $n$-categories need to be able to capture a lot of phenomena.

Comment: @goblin: in particular I think everyone in this discussion is totally fine with defining monoids as algebras over an operad instead of privileging the binary operation. But if you want to define $5$-categories as algebras over some operad-like object then you still have to do a lot of work to figure out exactly what operad-like object and what exactly it would mean to be an algebra over it. And then you need to be able to use your definition to do something! As far as I can tell (and no offense to Todd), I don't think anyone's ever used Todd Trimble's definition to do anything.

Comment: Sure, but my point was really that fruits of this *kind* of thinking haven't been exhausted. The same thinking that led people to combine $(h \circ g) \circ f$ and $h \circ (g \circ f)$ into a "central" canonical form $h \circ g \circ f$ can be applied to more difficult issues, and repeatedly applying it pays dividends in the currency of simplicity. Lol at your comment about Trimble $n$-categories.

Comment: @goblin: I welcome you to write down a definition of a $5$-category along these lines. I think, again, that this is only one stumbling block, and there are other bigger ones.

Answer (score 3):

As Qiaochu said, it's all about the coherence diagrams. The first non-trivial one is the pentagon axiom in the definition of a [monoidal category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category), which also appears in the definition of a (weak) $2$-category. An excellent introduction into higher categories is given in

> John Baez, James Dolan, *Categorification*, http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9802029

If you want to dive more into the subject, you might want to consult

> Tom Leinster, *Higher operads, Higher categories*, http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305049